# Anabelian geometry for cyclic extensions.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, arithmetic

Suppose $K$ is a number field and $K(\zeta_{\infty})$ is the field adjoined with ALL roots of unity. Then,

Q. Is it possible to reconstruct the field $K(\zeta_{\infty})$ from the aboslute Galois group ${\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{\Bbb Q}/K(\zeta_{\infty}))$?

As long as we consider the algebraic number field $K$, a theorem of Uchida ensures that $K$ is recovered purely from the Galois group ${\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{\Bbb Q}/K)$. Over all roots of unity, does the anabelian algorithm collapse?

Comment: A conjecture of Shafarevich predicts that the Galois group of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ over $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{\infty}) = \mathbf{Q}^{\mathrm{ab}}$ is a free pro-finite group of countable rank. But that implies the corresponding group with $\mathbf{Q}$ replaced by $K$ (which will have finite index in the previous group) is also a free profinite group (also of countable rank). So if the Shafarevich conjecture is true, then the Galois group you are considering is actually independent of $K$ for a number field $K$.

Comment: Great thanks! So we cannot go over to ${\Bbb Q}(\zeta_{\infty})$. Gotcha!